# Combinations on selecting one element for each index out of 3 arrays

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations, real-numbers

Given 3 non-sorted indexed sequence of real numbers. How many combinations are there on selecting exactly one element out of 3 elements (one from each array) with same index?

```
First array : a1, a2, a3, ..., an
Second array : b1, b2, b3, ..., bn
Third array : c1, c2, c3, ..., cn

One combination on selecting one element from each index is
a1, b2, c3, a4, b5, c6, ... ,cn
```

How many such combinations are there? My answer for this is `3^n`, i.e., each index has 3 choices. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your answer and explanation are correct.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian